# "Devel::Cover: Can't open test.pl for MD5 digest: No such file or directory" after switching user

Tags: perl, code-coverage

I'm using Devel::Cover to collect my perl coverage on linux but i got a problem when i tried to switch users. Following are steps to reproduce:

1. having 2 users : user1 and user2 and set `$PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover=-db,`[path to coverage folder]
2. login as user1 and place a test.pl at `/home/user1/`
3. run perl`/home/user1/test.pl`
4. switch to user2 by run `"sudo su - user2"`

error message `"Devel::Cover: Can't open test.pl for MD5 digest: No such file or directory"`is seen right after the user is changed

I tried getting it work by setting the arguments in PERL5OPT like:

```
export PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover=-db,[path to coverage folder],+inc,/var/home,/home
```

But it didn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe you using ~/test.pl somewhere and $HOME not setting after su? Print env in both case, maybe you found something.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the env looks good

Comment: I usually discourage people from asking this kind of question, but I'm really stumped here. Why do you want to change user? Are you doing so while Devel::Cover is still running or after it's finished? If the former, why are you surprised if Devel::Cover complains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, finally i figured out a solution by myself - to only include the folder i wanted to collect the coverage information using "-dir":

```
export PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover=-db,[path to coverage folder],-dir,[Paths of perl scripts to cover]
```

Comment: If you want to set options for Devel::Cover, you can just use the DEVEL_COVER_OPTIONS environment variable.  

i.e.:  

    `export DEVEL_COVER_OPTIONS=-db,[path to coverage folder],-dir,[Paths of perl scripts to cover]`

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the docs, when we pass the `-dir` parameter, we just define the directory in which the coverage data will be collected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that user2 can access /home/user1/test.pl?  This sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: user2 has the access to /home/user1/test.pl. But it's good point, i just tried run perl /home/user1/test.pl with user2, and i get the error message for 3 times! interesting....